# Finding permutations with foldl/map?

Tags: dictionary, functional-programming, scheme, fold

The professor showed us a drawn-out method to find all permutations of a list, i.e. (a b c) => ((a b c) (a c b) (b a c) (b c a) (c b a) (c a b)), but she said it could be done much more efficiently with foldl or map.

Totally new to the functional mindset. I cannot figure this out for the life of me.

Comment: You might want to clarify a bit: did your professor mean "more efficient" in the sense that it would run (asymptotically) faster, or "more efficient" in that it would be less code? Map and Foldl wind up popping out of nearly every list iteration problem in Scheme, so the comment is not surprising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are scheme versions (you mensioned "foldl" so there is haskell version too on this page) on http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Permutations#Scheme:

```
(define (insert l n e)
  (if (= 0 n)
      (cons e l)
      (cons (car l) 
            (insert (cdr l) (- n 1) e))))

(define (seq start end)
  (if (= start end)
      (list end)
      (cons start (seq (+ start 1) end))))

(define (permute l)
  (if (null? l)
      '(())
      (apply append (map (lambda (p)
                           (map (lambda (n)
                                  (insert p n (car l)))
                            (seq 0 (length p))))
                     (permute (cdr l))))))
```

Comment: The question is about Scheme, not Clojure or LISP. Edit: Also, you did not use fold....

Comment: The Haskell version uses foldr, not foldl (or fold-left)... And why mention Haskell???

Comment: @leppie The topic starter mentioned about solution with foldl OR map. Also examples are helpful to understand functional approach to the problem that can be applied to scheme version solution too.

Comment: @leppie My bad. Just didn't notice "scheme" tag. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

How about this one?

```
#lang racket    
(define l '(apple banana cheese desk))
(remove-duplicates (for/list ([i 1000000]) (shuffle l)))
```

Naturally, you'll want to increase the constant for long lists....

(#nothelpfulsorry)